# AWS bean stalk and Spring integration

Tags: java, python, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I successfully set up a spring boot application to aws using beanstalk

SpingBootAws2Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAws2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAws2Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

ServletInitializer.java

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootAws2Application.class);
    }

}
```

My question is, is it possible for me to execute a python algorithm file that was SSH'd into aws earlier?

I am planning to take in a jsonstring by using a GET method. Then pass that json string into a python algorithm. Then send back results from that algorithm.

Please let me know if this do-able

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Use a spring RestTemplate to make your GET request.
Retrieve the result as a string and path it to python.

This tutorial shows [three ways to run python from java](https://bytes.com/topic/python/insights/949995-three-ways-run-python-programs-java)

Comment: to add to my previous question. Will this still be possible if the python algo requires mongodb integration?

Comment: also, how would I obtain the path to the python file if it's outside of bean stalk?